# Getting access token and refresh token without asking for user permission

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

I want to access Google Drive to upload files using Google.Apis.Drive.v3.
Here is my code:

```
protected async void btnConnectGoogleDrive_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] Scopes = { DriveService.Scope.Drive };
    UserCredential credential;
    credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            new ClientSecrets
            {
                ClientId = "",
                ClientSecret = ""
            },
            Scopes,
            "user",
            CancellationToken.None);

    InsertGoogleDriveToken(credential.Token.AccessToken, areaID, "accesstoken");
    InsertGoogleDriveToken(credential.Token.RefreshToken, areaID, "refreshtoken");

    // Create Drive API service.
    var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = "SocialLadder",
    });

    GoogleDriveUpload(service, areaID);
}
```

Here I am able to get the AccessToken and RefreshToken but user is not redirected to permission page, so when I try to upload images to drive it gives me error that "permission_not_granted". Used same thing in MVC and that works great.

Please help me with this issue.

Comment: Are you using a service account or a regular user account?

Comment: I am using regular user account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you have changed your scopes.  You need to authenticate the user.  Do one of the following

- Go to %appdata% and delete the creditlas file for this user.
- change "user" to something else say "user1"

Your application should then require the user to authenticate again.

Comment: there is no file in %appdata%. But changing the "user" to "user1" worked like charm. 
Can I know what is "user" ?? and is it good if I user useremail instead of "user" ??

Comment: file datastore stores the credentials file denoted by the user you send it [my blog post here](https://www.daimto.com/google-net-filedatastore-demystified/)  email is an good idea or the user id

Comment: Thank you so much @DalmTo for your help.

Comment: One more question what if I want to save access token and refresh token in database instead of storing them in a file ? 
Basically what I want to do is I want to run an background job which uploads new images form server to google drive on daily basis. So I didn't want user to authenticate every time.